# Google Chrome shuts down when my MacBook Air goes to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, system-settings

No error messages come up and upon initiating Google Chrome again, it goes to my homepage.  I have gone into System Preferences and then to Security & Privacy and auto logout is disabled.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Mac is set to automatically log you out after a period of inactivity.

Open System Preferences from the Apple menu in the top-left corner. Open the "Security & Privacy" preference pane. Click on the "Advanced..." button in the bottom-right corner. You may need to unlock the pane using the padlock icon in the bottom-left corner.

I think you'll find "Log out after XX minutes of inactivity" ticked. Untick it.

Advanced settings within Security & Privacy

If not work, try to uninstall and re-install software.